# Using variables in BigQuery to calculate other variables

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to use a sampling column that randomly selects a number from 0-9999 to lighten the load of some queries since they don't all have to be exact. So, I want to be able to use a different sampling rate for each query, and based on the rate used, I need to apply a multiplier to a number of other columns.

I would like to use calculated variables to avoid making a bunch of edits in my code for each query.

I'm trying to do something like this,

```
declare sample int64 default 1;
declare multiplier decimal default 10000/sample;
```

This doesn't work though, I get a coercion error saying that the multiplier variable cannot be coerced into a decimal. So, I tried using a float64 on the multiplier and it returns all 0's.

I'm pretty new to BQ and would appreciate some feedback since I'm sure I'm overlooking something. Does anyone know how to use calculated variables like this in BigQuery?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

float64 is the right datatype.

```
declare sample int64 default 3;
declare multiplier float64 default 10000/sample;
declare multiplier_int int64 default  cast( multiplier as int64);

select sample, multiplier,multiplier_int
```